# How to change font color on child when parent class is added by jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have jquery sticky.js script to stick menu on scroll.

I want to change font color when sticky element **.is-sticky**, and back to normal color when **.is-sticky** is removed.

So i have this markup

```
<div id="sticky-wrapper" class="sticky-wrapper **is-sticky**">
    <div id="menu">
        <ul class="menu">
            <li><a href="#" title="xxx">XXX</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" title="xxx">YYY</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" title="xxx">ZZZ</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#sticky-wrapper .menu > li > a {color: #fff;}
#sticky-wrapper > .is-sticky .menu > li > a {color: #000;}
```

Does not work... Or maybe css will not support this case correctly?

EDIT. IMHO it's not the same question, and example case is better to understand for beginners.

Comment: Where does your is-sticky class is added?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change css rule to

```
#sticky-wrapper.is-sticky .menu > li > a {color: #000;}
```

Comment: So " > " make that large difference! Many thanks! :) Have a nice day and V for this answer!

Comment: @PipBoy2000 please accept the answer if it helps you

Comment: Sure mate! SO have 10 min threshold from question to accept :)

Comment: @PipBoy2000 welcome:)